# PhpStorm debugger stopping at break points but not displaying output until program's end

Tags: php, phpstorm, xdebug

My struggles to get PhpStorm installed are bearing some fruit, but I am still having at least one nagging issue.

I have created two configurations for running code in one of the browsers.  One is for the built-in web server using port 63342, and the other uses port 80. Xdebug is installed and verifies inside the connection for the port 80 config.

If I choose any one of the browser buttons in PhpStorm, the code runs in the selected browser but using the configured port.  Further, if I select the config for port 80, make sure the browser bug is listening, and then press PhpStorm's  debug button, the external browser loads, and then pauses at the break point I set.  If I go into PhpStorm I can then step through the program.  So far so good!

But, the stepping doesn't affect what is being output to the browser or the debugging panel's output display (or console) until the program gets past all the breakpoints. (It does show the stepping.) Only after the code is done executing does the output appear.  So, if I have a three line program, each with its own echo statement, and put a breakpoint  before the second line I would expect to see the output from the echo statement from the first line.  Unfortunately, I don't see anything output until the program completes.  This just doesn't seem right.

Any ideas?

Seems like I'm closer than I've been.  Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you using output buffering by any chance?

Comment: Marcin, output_buffering is not enabled in the php.ini file, and I'm not making any explicit call to turn it on, so I don't think so.

Comment: This is either output buffering, you don't have a `\n` at the end, or your web server might be buffering something.

Comment: Looks like there was a duplicate (and subsequent) output_buffering directive that was screwing things up.  Thanks to both Marcin and Derick.

Comment: Following up:  When I now click on the debug icon in PhpStorm the browser opens, and then, in PhpStorm I can step through and see the output in the debug window.  However, it doesn't display anything in the browser window until the whole thing runs.  Is this expected behavior?